# select data from intermediate m2m table using Flask SqlAlchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I use Flask and SqlAlchemy. I have two tables: Items and Customers. Each customer can like many items and each item can be liked by many customers, so I use an intermediate table for m2m.
Here are  my tables

```
customers_favorite_items = db.Table(
    'customers_favorite_items',
    db.Column('customer_uuid', UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('customers.uuid')),
    db.Column('item_uuid', UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('items.uuid')),
)

class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)

class Customer(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'customers'

    uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32), nullable=False)
    favorite_items = db.relationship(
        'Item',
        secondary=customers_favorite_items,
        backref=db.backref('liked_by_customers', lazy=True)
    )
```

API user sends a list of item uuids and ask how many customers has liked each of them.
I can easily get this information using raw select:

```
SELECT `item_uuid`, COUNT(`item_uuid`) FROM `customers_favorite_lots` WHERE `item_uuid` IN :item_uuids GROUP BY `item_uuid`
```

How can I achieve this using SqlAlchemy without unnecessary joins?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly query the associative table for the information you need. This
is one way you can do it:

```py
def show_likes_for_items_in_list(item_ids: list):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        stmt = (
            select(
                customers_favorite_items.c.item_uuid,
                func.count(customers_favorite_items.c.item_uuid)
            )
            .where(customers_favorite_items.c.item_uuid.in_(item_ids))
            .group_by(customers_favorite_items.c.item_uuid)
        )
        result = session.execute(stmt)
        for item_id, count in result:
            print(f"Item #{item_id} has {count} like(s).")
```

You pass a list of item IDs to the function, and it will show you the number of
likes for each item in the list. Since there is only one table involved, there
will be no joins.